# Easier way to earn the 'Clubber' Achievement for Party Hard?

Tags: achievements, party-hard

There is an achievement for Party Hard which requires you to launch the game 100 times:

[image: Clubber: Play Party Hard 100 times]

Normally I'd probably just earn this from regular gameplay, but having completed the game, the bonus content and pretty much every other achievement in around 4 game sessions, this achievement is going to be tedious to earn.

Is there any way to speed up or otherwise make this process a little quicker?

Comment: [Meta Discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10969/28182) for those interested :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using the [Steam Browser Protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) and some batch commands, I've written a small script that will launch and quit the game 100 times in order to unlock the achievement.

1. Copy the text below into Notepad, and save the file as any name, but make sure it is using the `.bat` extension.
2. Start Steam
3. Double click the file, and a command prompt window will open.
4. The game will open and close every 10 seconds 100 times. It's best to leave your computer for half-an-hour or so as it does it's thing.

So without further ado, here's the script:

```
@echo off

echo Setting Steam Status to offline
start steam://friends/status/offline

echo Beginning loop
for /l %%a in (0,1,100) do (
    start steam://run/356570
    timeout 10
    taskkill /IM PartyHardGame.exe 
    timeout 10
)
echo Loop complete! 

echo You should now have the Clubber Achievement

echo Setting Steam Status to online
start steam://friends/status/online
```

To explain what it does:

- `@echo off` This just stops the command prompt from stating every command as they're run. Nothing special.
- `start steam://friends/status/offline` - This sets your Steam availability/status to 'Offline'. This way, you won't be causing constant popups on your friends' PCs.
- `for /l %%a in (0,1,100)` - This is the loop part. This counts from the number 0 to the number 100, adding 1 each time (hence the `0,1,100`). Once it reaches 100 the loop will stop. Everything after `do` and inside the brackets `()` will be looped 100 times.
- `start steam://run/356570` This starts the game. The number is the Application ID of *Party Hard*, change this if you want to do this for a different game.
- `taskkill /IM PartyHardGame.exe` This will quit the application.
- The `timeout`'s are to give the application time load up and count towards the achievement, and for Steam to sync the changes once it quits.

  - You can adjust these if your PC is more/less powerful and takes less/more time to load the game, just make sure that the Achievement is still registering when you do!
- The `echo`'s are just informational, you can strip them out if you wish.

Comment: Have a +1 from me, my friend. There's nothing better than implementing code into a solution :)

Comment: +1 from me because I had no idea that the Steam Browser Protocol existed!

Comment: Your question and answer were posted within 60 seconds of each other...

Comment: @Nelson - actually they were posted at exactly the same time :). [There's nothing wrong with posting a question along with an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) - in fact, [there's a checkbox](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4680/28182) when asking a question if you want to provide an answer along with it (which is what I did)

Comment: Didn't say it was wrong :)  It was just obviously pre-edited and formatted and both the question and answer went up basically at the same time :)

Comment: @Nelson - Fair enough :). Well when you click that checkbox when asking a question you get a space to fill out the answer as well, and when you're done you hit 'Post your Question and Answer', so it's all automatic :)